# Table Paginator y Table Sort Devuelve Vacío En Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Estoy realizando 3 tablas en un componente componente, pero para no realiza la misma estructura ya que comparten los mismos campos y la genere asi:

En el html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc" >

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Auth_Area">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Auth_Area </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.Auth_Area}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Comentarios">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Comentarios </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.Comentarios}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Fecha">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Fecha </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.Fecha}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="NumTrabajador">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>NumTrabajador </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.NumTrabajador}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"> </mat-row>

</mat-table>

<mat-paginator #paginator
               [length]="this.dataSource.data ? this.dataSource.data.legth : 0"
               [pageSize]="5"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
               [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
               (page)="onPageChange($event)"
               >
</mat-paginator>
```

En el ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabla',
  templateUrl: './tabla.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabla.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { read: true, static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { read: true, static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  @Input() data: any[];
  public displayedColumns = ['Auth_Area', 'Comentarios', 'Fecha', 'NumTrabajador'];
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.data.currentValue)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(changes.data.currentValue);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([this.data]);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      console.log(this.paginator);
      console.log(this.sort);
    } );
  }
}
```

Para poder mandar la información lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
this.PTService.RegistrosOACalidad(this.OTBusqueda).subscribe(
      data => { this.datosCalidad = data}
    );

    this.PTService.RegistrosOATesFin(this.OTBusqueda).subscribe(
      data => { this.datosTesFin = data }
    );

    this.PTService.RegistrosOAEmbarques(this.OTBusqueda).subscribe(
      data => { this.datosEmbarques = data }
    );
```

y en el html lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
<app-tabla [data]='this.datosEmbarques'> </app-tabla>

<app-tabla [data]='this.datosCalidad'> </app-tabla>

<app-tabla [data]='this.datosTesFin'> </app-tabla>
```

A lo cual si plasma la información, se generan las tablas, pero el paginado no esta reconociendo ninguna longitud, por eso lo imprimí en consola y aparece como indefinido, por eso realice lo siguiente:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { read: true, static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { read: true, static: false }) sort: MatSort;
```

Pero aun así sigue marcando indefinido y no funciona el paginado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos problemas principales en tu código:

El primero es que en los `@ViewChild` has añadido una opción `read: true`, la cual está impidiendo que el decorador obtenga la referencia correcta a los elementos. Por tanto tienes que eliminar dicha opción y dado que el valor por defecto de `static` es `false`, puedes simplificar esa parte del código de la siguiente manera:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

Si quieres saber más de cómo funciona `@ViewChild` puedes ver este [video](https://youtu.be/EmeAeWN3lXw)

---

Y el segundo fallo potencial que veo, es que estás creando diferentes `MatTableDataSource`

- Primero estás creando uno en `ngAfterViewInit`, en el que sí asignas la referencia al `paginator` y al `sort`.
- Y posteriormente estás creando un nuevo `MatTableDataSource` cada vez que cambie el input `data`. En este, a diferencia del de `ngAfterViewInit` no estás asignando las referencias, por lo que no se vincularían ni el paginator ni el sorter.

Para resolver este posible problema, puedes modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
export class TablaComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  //creamos un único dataSource
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  
  // covertimos el input data en un setter para que cada vez que cambie el 
  // input asignar el nuevo valor al data del dataSource
  @Input() set data(newData: any[]) {
    this.dataSource.data = newData;
  }

  ...
  
  // eliminamos ngOnChanges ya que no es necesario con el setter.
  

  //asignamos el paginator y el sort al datasource una vez la vista este inicializada.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; 
  }
}
```

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, lo solucione así en el componente tabla.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
  }
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
  }


public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(changes.data.currentValue);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;    
  }
```

Lo que entendí leyendo en foros es lo mismo que el vídeo que me compartiste, y solamente así solucione la parte de que en otro componente llamarlas como lo había puesto desde el inicio.